# Write a lot of file to one file and read it

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, filesystems

I have service worked with lot of files

1) read from some place

2) write it to disk

3) store files with no delete

4) get web request for file

5) read from disk

6) write content to web response

First time it was worked fine, but now there is 4 000 files (27gb) and there is a problems with file system couse of this number of files.

I want to write all files to one file and then read them from this file. Is there a best practices for it or libraries?

Any advices are welcome!

p.s.

1) service working now on asp.core 2.0 + linux

2) main problem now is memory leak (lot of file descriptors?) and file system max descriptors count

3) service creates long diretory hierarchy (7 levels), so there is 6 000 000 folders

Comment: "I want to write all files to one file" No, you don't want that, especially if all the files together are 27 GB. The longer your file, the more resources are necessary to read and write from it, and the slower it will be. Reading and writing to a 27 GB file would almost assuredly bring your server down completely.

Comment: Even if I'll read with offset?

Comment: this problem seems self inflicted... should you use DBMS?

Comment: unclear why you have 4000+ files... and why you need them

Comment: It's some kind of file storage with logic. I'm not shure database is best solution here

Comment: but file based doesn't seem like a good idea either.  You are asking to consolidate into one file, then seek to position... that doesn't seem like a long term solution.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use one file, you'll have threading/performance issues.

When I do this, I create a temp file, write to it.. then read the contents out similar to you.  Then delete it.

```
  try
  {
    string filename = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() + "_" + bidScenarioId.ToString();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);

    …

  }
  finally
  {
     System.IO.File.Delete(filename);
  }
```

Comment: Yeap, but i need to store it and read on request (I've update question)